# What version of StructureMap can I use in webform app (Net 2.0)

Tags: asp.net-2.0, structuremap

I am bit confuse. I would like to use StructureMap in my webform app, but it is still Net 2.0. I am not really sure which version I should use.

Anyone using StructureMap for Net 2.0 project? Which version?

Thanks for any response. X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you have to use Structure Map 2.0 or earlier.