# IoC container for .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, ioc-container

Very simple: what is in your opinion the best framework (for a IoC container) to use if .NET 2.0 is the limitation?

Comment: Note: I've had difficulty finding the .net 2 version of Windsor, it looks like that the last version that supported it was RC3; that is the reason for asking this question...

Comment: One helpful question about StructureMap version for .NET 2.0:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666151/what-version-of-structuremap-can-i-use-in-webform-app-net-2-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the distributions of the libraries are only compatible with 3.5 and 4.0.

But, as most of them are open source, you can try to compile by yourself.

Give a shot to StructureMap:

https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/tree/v2.0

I think the last .net 2.0 compatible version was 2.0 as well and thanks to github switching to that tag is very easy

Comment: yeah, that the same problem I've encountered, most libraries are .NET 3.5+ ... The question remains, if we compare Structure Map 2, and Castle RC3, and all the other .NET 2.0 IoC containers, which is "better" or at least in the same area of the possibilities...

Comment: It depends on your requirements about the library. I think the basic functionality of a IoC is quite simple, so I don't think you will have any problem. But, if you cannot use >.NET 2.0, your only choice is to use the tools there are available :)

Answer (score 5):

We use [Unity 1.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647347.aspx) for .NET 2.0 application. It is compatible even with .NET 2.0 RTM.

We also tried to use [Unity 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff663144.aspx), it's more modern and mature, the benefits of Unity 2.0 over Unity 1.2 are the following:

1. Unity 2.0 exception message is not so scary as in Unity 1.2
2. it is more integrated into Enterprise Library (5.0)
3. it contains less assemblies.

But we failed to use it with .NET 2.0 RTM. But if you have .NET 2.0 SP1 or SP2, it's more likely that you can use Unity 2.0 if you manually deploy some assemblies from .NET 3.5 (like System.Core.dll). We failed to switch to Unity 1.2 because some of our clients don't have any service packs for .NET 2.0 and we can't force them to install these service packs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about best, but in terms of us having no issues in a large production environment, then we used the [Unity Application Block 1.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649080.aspx) to great effect in the past.